# Add object as value to to a parent object inside of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to map through my  `results` array and 6 components.

The first three components will render the results of `location1` and the last three components will render the results of `location2`.

However, I am having a bit of difficulty trying to figure out how to structure the data inside of my `results` array.

Here is what I have and it's incorrect:

```js
const results = [
    (location1: {
      result: { name: "Rome, Italy", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
      result: { name: "Beijing, China", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
      result: { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
    }),
    (location2: {
      result: { name: "Rome, NY", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
      result: { name: "Spain", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
      result: { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
    }),
  ];
```

Comment: Replace square brackets with curly braces and remove the parenthesis

Comment: Each occurance of `(location` should be `{location` and '})` should be `}}`2, replace `[` with `{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make it a valid array of objects.

```js
const locations = [
    {
      results: [
        { name: "Rome, Italy", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
        { name: "Beijing, China", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
        { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
      ]
    },
    {
      results: [
        { name: "Rome, NY", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
        { name: "Spain", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
        { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
      ]
    },
  ];
  
console.log(locations[0].results[0].name);
```

That way you can easily loop trough it.

```js
const locations = [
    {
      results: [
        { name: "Rome, Italy", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
        { name: "Beijing, China", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
        { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
      ]
    },
    {
      results: [
        { name: "Rome, NY", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
        { name: "Spain", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
        { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
      ]
    },
  ];
  
let html = '';
locations.forEach(location => {
  html += '<div class="location"><ul>';
  location.results.forEach(result => {
    html += `<li>${result.name}</li>`
  })
  html += '</ul></div>'
});

let locations_element = document.getElementById('locations');
locations_element.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.location {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="locations"></div>
```

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`template ${literals}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are used.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways you could restructure your data, but I would try the following.

```
const results = {
    location1: [
      { name: "Rome, Italy", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
      { name: "Beijing, China", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
      { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
    ],
    location2: [
      { name: "Rome, NY", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 },
      { name: "Spain", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 },
      { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 },
    ],
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

location1 and location2 should be also an array (an object can't have more fields with the same name).

```
const results = [
    {location1: [
      {result: { name: "Rome, Italy", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 }},
      {result: { name: "Beijing, China", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 }},
      {result: { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 }},
    ]},
    {location2: [
      {result: { name: "Rome, NY", price: 100, distance: 1299, match: 96 }},
      {result: { name: "Spain", price: 200, distance: 3000, match: 93 }},
      {result: { name: "California, USA", price: 250, distance: 420, match: 75 }},
    ]},
  ];
```